# Sharepoint Javascript API for overlaid calendar events

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, calendar

I have a main calendar with another overlaid calendar from sub site.

I am using **SPServices** library and able to retrieve Calendar events but not events from sub site's calendar. Can this be achieved using SPServices or I need a different approach?

What I discovered is that, when I open the calendar, a few POST ajax requests call to **/CalendarServices.ashx** to get overlaid calendar events. I tried to make request to this handler using jQuery but it seems like you can not access this handler directly.

Any ideas guys?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's the trick. **Overlaid Calendar is tied to List's view**

1/ Find out which **list's view** to which you add the overlay calendar (probably it is the default view which is **Calendar**)

2/ Use JSOM to get the view object

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
var view = list.get_views().getByTitle('Calendar');
context.load(view);
```

3/ Log that view info on console to go through its member. Follow **view.$5_0.$H_0.HtmlSchemaXml** property path, you'll get something like below

(**NOTE**: I am working with SP 2013, so you might need to check again for proper property path)

[image]

4/ What you're looking for is **AggregationCalendar** section, in my case there're 2 of them. From here, you can use the list id to query the list items.

Have fun :)